# FATAL: using recovery command file "recovery.conf" is not supported while postgresql replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.scalingpostgres.com/tutorials/postgresql-streaming-replication/) to get a replication of PostgreSQL DB
this is the [connected Vlog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaPnYQBBdyU).
while running the following command
`sudo pg_ctlcluster 14 replica1 start`
I got this error:

> Job for postgresql@14-replica1.service failed because the service did
> not take the steps required by its unit configuration. See "systemctl
> status postgresql@14-replica1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for
> details.

I have tried checking the logs using
`systemctl status postgresql@14-replica1.service`

This is my log
[image]

```
restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/replica1/%f %p' 
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=rep_user passfile=''/var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass'' host''/var/run/postgresql'' port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres target_session_attrs=any'
archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/replica1 %r'
```

Here's the result of my **pg_lsclusters**

[image]

I think the issue is with the recovery.conf file

Comment: Could it be that you're mixing postgres 10 and 14? At least it is what your commands suggest. A postgres 14 cannot be the replica of a postgres 10. Side note: PostgreSQL 10 will reach EOL in less than 2 months, so deploying it now is not recommended.

Comment: Also, postgres 14 does not use `recovery.conf` anymore ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response @JimJones
Yes I just found out that recovery.conf has been replaced. Having all these settings in postgres.conf worked for me